# How to show a div infront of a menu while clicking on the home contact blog and services page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

### Web developer

Its loving to see such kind of effects on the screen i am in love with css 3d dimensions its feel like i am in 3D space and creating it so much fun man loved it and gonna be doing this liking

$(document).ready(function(){


                $("#contact").click(function(){
                    $(".content").load("contact.html .data");
                });

                $("#about").click(function(){
                    $(".content").load("about.html .data");
                });

                $("#blog").click(function(){
                    $(".content").load("blog.html .data");
                });

                $("#services").click(function(){
                    $(".content").load("services.html .data");
                });
            });

Comment: Hello imran, please add the code to your question and be precise in what you are asking. Also let us know what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Please share your code so that experts can help you. Without code it is difficult to understand what issue are you facing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SessionStrage to save data and pull out it on other pages.

This works as Key-Value type storage.
So you have to put key name and value

```
// Save Data
sessionStorage.setItem('UserName', 'Tom');

// Get Data (You can get your data in any page you want to get them after saving data)
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('UserName');
console.log(data);  // Display "Tom"

// Delete Data
sessionStorage.removeItem('UserName');
```

This SessionSotrage only works in a session.
This means if the user closes the window, the data will be gone.
So please use it when the data is temporary.